# How can I call JNI code from an EJB in JBoss

Tags: java, jboss, java-native-interface, ejb

I am trying to call a native VOIP library from an EJB.
However, on

```
System.loadLibrary(...)
```

JBoss shuts down: it says it received an ABRT and shuts down.

I know about JCA, but I'm looking for a more pragmatic solution. Is there a (low effort) way of calling a JNI function from an EJB?

(using JBoss EAP 6 + Java 6 on SLES 11 64bit)

------>
Thanks for the helpful answers! I implemented a small external java app that encapsulates the jni stuff and offers a webservice.

Comment: JCA is the proper solution in this case and is rather simple to implement once you figure out what interface and class to implement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't done EJB for a few years but unless it has changed since, one of the EJB restrictions is that you can't call native code.

How I worked around this was from EJB, I could make a call to a RMI server and a JNI call can happen from there.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I am looking for a "smaller" solution without the effort to have an extra server. Any idea?

Comment: Do you have to use EJB? If not, the only suggestion would be port your code to run with another container (tomcat?). Otherwise, you could consider porting your native functionality to pure java. The EJB restriction on running native code is non-negotiable :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I implemented a single application that offers a webservice that encapsulates the jni.